# Jordan curve; is the inside mapped to the inside by a homeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology

> Suppose that
>
> - $\gamma:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}^2$ is a closed simple curve;
> - $U$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that contains both the image $|\gamma|$ of $\gamma$ and the inside $D$ of $\gamma$;
> - $f:U\to V$ is a homeomorphism, where $V$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}^2$.
>
> Is it true that the inside of the closed simple curve $f\circ\gamma $
>   is $f(D)$?

Intuitively, it seems true. But I can neither prove nor disprove it. Can anyone answer this question? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$U\setminus |\gamma|$ may have several components $C$ (it's not given
that $U$ is connected), but only one with the property that $C\cup|\gamma|$ is
compact, namely $C=D$. The image of $D$ under $f$ must have the same property
with respect to $V$, so $f(D)$ is the interior of $f(\gamma)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can we be sure that there is only one component of $U-|\gamma|$ with the property stated in your answer?